# How to delete values from core data in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

for example here is the portion of my code that adds values

```
do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "users")
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        if results.count > 0 {
            for item in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                let fName = item.valueForKey("firstName")
                let lName = item.valueForKey("lastName")
                print(lName!, lName!)
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print("There was error getting data")
    }
```

Let's say I have 10 users and now I want to

1. Delete users with `lastName` of "DOW"
 2. First 2 users and last 2 users?
 3. Also, all users with the `lastName` starts with "D"

Thanks
Borna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can code:

```
if results.count > 0 {
    for item in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
        let fName = item.valueForKey("firstName") as! String
        let lName = item.valueForKey("lastName")
        print(lName!, lName!)
        if fName.contains("DOW"){
            appDelegate.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(item)
        }
    }
}
```

OR just get object what you want what NSPredicate and delete it 
code:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "users")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName beginswith[c] %@", "D")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do{
        let fetchResults = try appDelegate.managedObjectContext..executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        if fetchResults.count>0 {
              appDelegate.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(fetchResults[0])
        } else {
            // no data
        }
    }catch{
        //error
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I got confused by this portion  of the code
appDelegate.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(data)  

What is (data) and appDelegate?

Comment: Sorry, my false. data is item and appDelegate  :S , not good  if you don't know (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IDfgATVqHw)

Comment: Thanks so much. Got it working  
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)

Answer (score 0):

This question sounds like homework.  The problem with deleting the first 2 and last 2 items is the data is stored unordered. You may get a different set of data from fetch request unless a sort order is provided.